# Login into desktop via SSH

Tags: gnome, ssh, login

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04 which I use with an monitor to display stuff.
I don't have a mouse/keyboard connected, only connection per SSH.
When the server starts (it runs gnome desktop) I have to login.
Is there a way to login per SSH only (not VNC)?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to set up automatic login?

Comment: I guess that would be the simplest solution...
Just thought it would be bad practice and searched for another way.

Comment: I think an important question is why. X in this setup is meant for processing local input if you want X over a network look into XDMCP or VNC depending on your goals. If you're trying to use a remote keyboard and mouse locally then there are options but they take much more then ssh to get running.

Comment: @Pix3l if it's bad practice depends on what the machine is used for. If it's a public kiosk or digital signage, it's not a bad practice. If it's an internal workstation where the strategy plans for a fortune 500 company's stored, it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

While I think this sounds a lot like the xy problem, your best bet is to probably disable GUI login, then login to ssh and manually run `startx`

Unfortunately, this is a bit more complicated and will depend a lot on your setup, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

To get into a fresh Ubuntu 18.4.2-LTS with putty on a win10 computer I had to **install openssh server** as there was no ssh daemon listening. (I added myself to the group dialout but that might not be related.)  After installing SSH and disabling the firewall I tested the connection and it worked with the username and password given during install. Not with other usernames.